# Prove sequence convergence using Cauchy Sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences

How should I prove convergence using Cauchy sequences $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin({k^{3}+1)}}{(4k+1)(4k+5)}  $$

I tried starting with the definition $\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n,p\geq N: |x_{n+p}-x_n|<\varepsilon$

$$ \left|\frac{\sin(2)}{(5)(9)} +\frac{\sin(9)}{(9)(13)}+ ...+\frac{\sin({n^{3}+1)}}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}+...+\frac{\sin({(n+p)^{3}+1)}}{(4(n+p)+1)(4(n+p)+5)}-\left(\frac{\sin(2)}{(5)(9)} +\frac{\sin(9)}{(9)(13)}+ ...+\frac{\sin({n^{3}+1)}}{(4n+1)(4n+5)}\right)\right|.$$

thus, after subtracting terms
$$\left|\frac{\sin({(n+1)^{3}+1)}}{(4n+5)(4n+9)}+...+\frac{\sin({(n+p)^{3}+1)}}{(4(n+p)+1)(4(n+p)+5)}\right|$$

Since $\:-1\leq \sin(x) \leq 1\:$ and $\:n^2 \lt (4n+5)(4n+9)$ then $$\left|\frac{\sin({(n+1)^{3}+1)}}{(4n+5)(4n+9)}+...+\frac{\sin({(n+p)^{3}+1)}}{(4(n+p)+1)(4(n+p)+5)}\right| \lt\sum_{}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}.$$

How do we find $n$ if the result of our greatest sum $\sum_{}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$, equals $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: You need a lot more modulus signs. But basically you have shown that $|x_{n+p}-x_n|<\sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{k^2}$. As the latter series is (as you know) convergent, it is Cauchy and so given $\epsilon$ you can find $n$ to  make $\sum_{k=n}^{n+p} \frac{1}{k^2} < \epsilon$. (You've just flung away too much too soon).

Comment: @ancientmathematician  Could you take a little bit more time to explain me what to do?

Comment: In fact it is set up to allow you to find an explicit $N$ without using the convergence of $\sum\frac{1}{k^2}$. See my answer.

Comment: By the way your statement of the Cauchy condition is non-standard and may even be wrong. You say $\forall n,p\geqslant N$ when you should say $\forall n\geqslant N, \forall p\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
|x_{n+p}-x_n|
& = &\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{\sin (k^2+1)}{(4k+1)(4k+5)}\right|\\
&\leqslant & \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \left|\frac{\sin (k^2+1)}{(4k+1)(4k+5)}\right|\\
& \leqslant& \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{(4k+1)(4k+5)}\\
&=& \frac14 \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \left(\frac{1}{(4k+1)}-\frac{1}{(4k+5)}\right)\\
&=& \frac14 \left( \frac{1}{4n+5} -\frac{1}{4(n+p)+5} \right)\\
&\leqslant & \frac{1}{4(4n+5)}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and so choosing $N>\frac{1}{16\epsilon}$ will provide an $N$ for you to use in proving that $\{x_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy.